# Is "At some dramatic moment" right?

Tags: word-usage

> At some dramatic moment in the story, the terrible secret becomes known and a reputation is ruined.

Why not use **At some dramatic moments** here?

Comment: Perhaps you are confused by the use of _some_. In this context, it means _an unspecified moment_, not _several different moments_.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when a secret becomes known, it is a single event, which occurs at one particular moment, not at several moments.

The expression "at some dramatic moment in the story" seems a bit odd. If one is referring to one particular story, then "a dramatic moment" would fit better. On the other hand, if one is referring to stories in general, then "some dramatic moment in the story" fits. But it would still be a single moment in any one story.